# Comparing dates in Entity SQL

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5, entity-sql

What is the correct eSQL syntax to compare dates?

The equivalent LINQ-to-Entities expression would look something like this:

```
var lastYearsShipments = from p in MyDataServiceContext.Products
                         where p.ShipDate.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year - 1
                         select p;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They say it's [acceptable to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq/119658#119658), so here goes ...

```
var predicate = string.Format(
    "Year(it.ShipDate) == Year(cast('{0}' as System.DateTime)) -1",
    System.DateTime.Now);

var lastYearsShipments = 
    myQuery.Products.Where(predicate); // myQuery is type ObjectQuery<T>
```

See also: [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string datetimeFormatter = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

var predicate = string.Format("Year(it.ShipDate) == Year(DATETIME'{0}')) -1", System.DateTime.Now.ToString(datetimeFormatter)); 

var lastYearsShipments = myQuery.Products.Where(predicate);
```